# (History) Books About Geometry of Curves and Surfaces

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, book-recommendation, surfaces, curves

Are there any books regarding how curvature, torsion, etc., did born? When these math notions were used for the first time?

Comment: See these articles by [Dirk Jan Struik](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirk_Jan_Struik): "Outline of a History of Differential Geometry" (https://www.jstor.org/stable/225188 and https://www.jstor.org/stable/224886). He mentions [Michel Ange Lancret](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michel_Ange_Lancret) as having used what is essentially the curvature and the torsion, in 1802.

Comment: The ["Earliest Known Uses of Some of the Words of Mathematics" site](http://jeff560.tripod.com/c.html) attributes "curvature" —specifically of circles, quantified as the reciprocal of radius— to 14th-century Nicole Oresme. Then, of course, Isaac Newton discussed curvature of a curve essentially via osculating circles. By the same source, ["torsion"](http://jeff560.tripod.com/t.html) as a *term* came about in 1825, replacing "flexion" (for which there is no reference).

Comment: The folks at the [History of Science and Mathematics StackExchange](https://hsm.stackexchange.com) may have more ready references for this kind of thing.

Comment: [This article](https://www.jstor.org/stable/41134348) (french) tells us the study of *curves with "double curvatures"* dates back to Clairaut. See his work *"Recherches sur les courbes à double courbure"* [here](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k96418918) (1731).

Comment: Spivak's Comprehensive Intro to Differential Geometry Vol. 2.